# Struggling with CSS button animation

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to replicate the button animation seen on this page:

https://www.beedie.ca/

Where the border changes color from the top left to bottom right.

I can get the left and the top to animate correctly, but then instead of the lines continuing down and across the bottom, a box expands out for the bottom and right. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.

I have attached my attempt at the code below. HTML and CSS.

```css
.hover-effect-button-container-yellow {
  max-width:150px;
  position:relative;
}

.hover-effect-button-yellow {
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid white;
  font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 25.5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.hover-effect-button-yellow:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.hover-effect-button-yellow:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.hover-effect-button-yellow:before {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.hover-effect-button-yellow:after {
  border-right:1px solid white;
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
}

.hover-effect-button-yellow:hover:before {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-top-color: red;
  border-left-color: red;
  transition: height 1s ease-out, width 1s ease-out;
}

.hover-effect-button-yellow:hover:after {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  border-right-color: red;
  transition: height 1s ease-out 1s, width 1s ease-out 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-effect-button-container-yellow">
    <div class="hover-effect-button-yellow"> 
        <a href="#">CLICK HERE</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give **class="button"** to `<a>` and give css to it.

You need to add whole border in **::before** and **::after** of the button:

```
.button::before, .button::after {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

and change the top right left bottom borders on hover of ::before and ::after selectors of button; also change the transition as shown:

```
.button:hover::before {
    border-top-color: #0076b6;
    border-right-color: #0076b6;
    transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
.button:hover::after {
    border-bottom-color: #0076b6;
    border-left-color: #0076b6;
    transition: height 0.25s ease-out, width 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
```

Please find updated css and html below:

```css
.button {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0.9rem 2rem;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
    color: #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "ff-meta-web-pro","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: color 0.25s;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.button::before, .button::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.button::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.button:hover {
    outline-width: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:hover::before {
    border-top-color: #0076b6;
    border-right-color: #0076b6;
    transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
.hover-effect-button-container-yellow {
    padding: 10px;
    background: pink;
}
.button:hover::before, .button:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.button:hover::after {
    border-bottom-color: #0076b6;
    border-left-color: #0076b6;
    transition: height 0.25s ease-out, width 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-effect-button-container-yellow">
   <div class="hover-effect-button-yellow"> 
      <a class="button" href="https://beedie.ca/industrial/">Learn More</a>
   </div>
</div>
```